# Error while executing query using OPENDATASOURCE

Tags: sql-server-2008

I connect to my database using SQL Authentication (non sa user) from SQL Server Management Studio. When I execute the following query, I get "Access to the remote server is denied because no login-mapping exists."

```
EXEC OPENDATASOURCE('SQLNCLI','Server=MyServer;Trusted_Connection=yes;').Database.dbo.myStoredProcedure
```

If I connect to SQL Server Management Studio as sa, the query executes without any error.

How to execute a OPENDATASOURCE query by connecting to SQL Server Management Studio as a non-sa user under sql authentication without providing username and password in the query?

Answer (score 0):

The sa account would execute the `OPENDATASOURCE` as the windows service account logon. 
This is one workaround.

```
EXEC N'
EXEC OPENDATASOURCE(''SQLNCLI'',''Server=MyServer;Trusted_Connection=yes;'').Database.dbo.myStoredProcedure'
AS LOGIN = 'sa';
```

But really you should setup your sql credentials on the remote server. 
Then replace Trusted Connection with your `User ID` and `Password`. 
If you don't want to add the user id and password in the query then set it up as a linked server.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179856(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: Note: to execute as sa you would need impersonate permissions or to be a sysadmin.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temporary linked server and then drop it. This will use the currently logged in SQL user credentials and assuming the same user exists on the other box it should work:

```
exec sp_addlinkedserver @server='MyServer', @srvproduct='SQL Server'
exec sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname='MyServer', @locallogin=null, @useself='True'
exec('exec [MyServer].Database.dbo.myStoredProcedure')
exec sp_dropserver 'MyServer', 'droplogins'
```